# Preventing Java annotation to be added to final field

Tags: java, annotations

```
@MyAnnotation
final Integer value;
```

Is it possible to configure a custom annotation MyAnnotation in a way that will cause a compile time error above, but no compile time error when added to a non-final field? (irrespective of access level).

Background info: in our code, we have a special annotation that triggers modification via reflection from an outside class and this cannot be done for final fields, so we'd like to warn users of the annotation at compile time (currently we have a runtime check that will throw an exception).

Comment: You can create an [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) which emits an error if `@MyAnnotation` is on a final field. You may not be able to enforce the annotation processor be used, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is an [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html). For example, if you have the following annotation:

```java
package com.example;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) // must be at least SOURCE
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Foo {}
```

Then the following will emit an error if `@Foo` is present on a `final` field:

```java
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor;
import javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedAnnotationTypes;
import javax.annotation.processing.SupportedSourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic.Kind;
import java.util.Set;

@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.Foo")
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_13) // or whatever version you support
public class FooProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

  @Override
  public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    if (!annotations.isEmpty()) {
      // This processor is only declared to process one annotation
      TypeElement foo = annotations.iterator().next();

      for (Element element : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(foo)) {
        for (AnnotationMirror mirror : element.getAnnotationMirrors()) {
          if (mirror.getAnnotationType().asElement().equals(foo)
              && element.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.FINAL)) {
            // processingEnv is a protected field of AbstractProcessor
            processingEnv.getMessager()
                .printMessage(Kind.ERROR, "Field cannot be final.", element, mirror);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

In the above code I only used the model API (e.g. `TypeElement`) to reference the `Foo` annotation. Note, however, that the annotation processor API does allow one to use the class of the annotation (e.g. `Foo.class`) if the annotation is visible (i.e. your processor has a dependency on the annotation). Using the class API can be easier to use, easier to reason about, and easier to read—use it if your annotation class is visible to your processor class.

---

You would then need to tell `javac` to use the annotation processor. See the [tool specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html) for more information; specifically, look at the `--processor-path`, `--processor-module-path`, `-processor`, and `-proc` standard options as well as [the section](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html#annotation-processing) on annotation processing.

Note you may not be able to enforce the use of your annotation processor.